# Setting up OpenFrameworks with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, openframeworks

I'm in the process of setting up my system to deploy OpenFrameworks apps on Android devices.

I've followed the instructions here to the letter: http://openframeworks.cc/setup/android-studio/

However, whenever I open one of the OF - Android example projects, I keep getting the following error:

[image]

I haven't turned up anything yet as far as what the issue may be (and this is my first foray to Android anything). Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because there are some spaces in your directory path in "Development Tools" and "3rd Party Tools". I've had weird issues in the past with openFrameworks and Android studio like the one you're having.

Try to put openFrameworks in a path structure without spaces. Maybe clone a fresh version to test.